# Magento 2: Display Product Attribute in CMS Page

Tags: magento2.2

I have created and product attribute which I am able to see it on Product View page i.e. addtocart.phtml

The below code work perfectly on product view page:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAffiliateLink(); ?>
```

I have to read this variable in CMS Home page where same code is not working.

I tried with below code as well but no luck:

```
<?php echo $_item->getAttributeText('affiliate_link'); ?>
```

Do I have to do anything special to show product attributes on CMS page in magento 2?

Comment: How did you get the $_item? if $_item is the same object than $_product in the above example, why don't use the same method: getAffiliateLink()?

Comment: I am getting the product in addtocart.phtml <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?> While I am getting list of Product in for loop in CMS Home Page via Magento_Catalog widget i.e. $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems(); <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>

Comment: create a block class to load the product and use the phtml file to show the product info, then search how to call a phtml file in CMS page. hope this will help u

Comment: I am getting all other attribute of product except the custom product attribute value e.g. $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) but not the affilate_link one. Do I need to create a block for custom product attribute?

Answer (score 0):

It's Resolved.
The Custom Product attribute was not visible for used in product listing. I have change the setting and reindex and after that I am able to get the custom product attributes in CMS page as well.